# how do i use substring to eliminate 0's in java

Tags: java

I want my code to take out 0's and put M,B,T ect. after 1,10,or 100, but I don't know how to do it.Basically The program is asking how much money you want like you would put 10000000000. Then kb gets that int, And int b gets length of a, but this is where I have a problem because I can't find a way to make the 10000000000 into 10, and then have it print 'You have $10T',

```
public class MinersHavenMoney_Client
{
 private final static String filename = "input.txt";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int x;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    MinersHavenMoney m1;
    m1 = new MinersHavenMoney();

    System.out.println("How much money do you want");
    int a = kb.nextInt();

    int b = String.valueOf(a).length();

    kb.close();
    if(b<=6)
    System.out.println("You have $" + a);
    else if(b>=7&&b<=9)
    System.out.println("You have $" + c + "M");
    else if(b>9&&b<=12)
    System.out.println("You have $" + a + "B");
    else if(b>12&&b<=15)
    System.out.println("You have $" + a + "T");
   //There is more but there is to much
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't enter `10000000000` into an `int`. You need a `long` to store such a large value.

Comment: Where is `c` defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of comparing the number of digits, you can compare the values.

```
public static String scale(double value) {
    return value <  1e3 ? asText(value) :
           value <  1e6 ? asText(value / 1e3) + "K" :
           value <  1e9 ? asText(value / 1e6) + "M" :
           value < 1e12 ? asText(value / 1e9) + "B" : 
                          asText(value / 1e12) + "T";
}

public static String asText(double d) {
     return (long) d == d ? Long.toString((long) d) : Double.toString(d);
}
```

Comment: @JornVernee should be ok now.

Comment: it works all the way to 100 million but says number is to big anything after that

Comment: @DwaneBrownJr what "says number is to big"?

Comment: The box that pops up

Comment: @DwaneBrownJr this doesn't pop up a box.

Comment: @DwaneBrownJr Running it here for 100 million print `100M` as expected. http://ideone.com/sbbwrK

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need a `long` to support values into trillions (`int` has the range -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1). Then you could use a *regular expression*. If the number ends in 12 0s it is *trillions*, 9 0s it is *billions*, 6 0s for *millions* and 3 0s for *thousands*. Something like,

```
long b = 10L * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(b).replaceAll("[0]{12}$", "T")
        .replaceAll("[0]{9}$", "B").replaceAll("[0]{6}$", "M")
        .replaceAll("[0]{3}$", "K"));
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
 10T
```

Comment: `String.valueOf(b).replaceAll("000$", "K").replace("000K", "M").replace("000M", "B").replace("000B", "T")`  ... only need "regex" for the first replacement.  ;-)